# Subscribed Assignment Dimension Mismatch - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dimension

I am trying to run this program, but it gets to "renamedDates(1, count)=datestr(dateNumber,formatOut);" and throws an error.  The reordertime is a row of Bluetooth timestamps, and I am trying to convert it into month/date/year format.  I don't know if I should use a cellstr instead to store the numeric strings instead.

```
time = [];
firstdevice = 1; 
while (firstdevice <= 104)
    for i=1:length(s(firstdevice).device_date) 
        time(1,i)=s(firstdevice).device_date(1,i);
    end
    firstdevice= firstdevice + 1;
end
reordertime = sort(time);

renamedDates=zeros(1,length(time));

count=5720;
while(count<= length(time))
       dateNumber = reordertime(1, count);
    formatOut='mm/dd/yy HH:MM:SS:FFF';
    renamedDates(1, count)=datestr(dateNumber,formatOut);
    count=count+1;
end
```

Comment: Do you realize that as you have this written all that ends up in `time` is `s(104).device_date(1,:)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing about what your inputs are and what you want.

I'm assuming your inputs are `struct`s filled with vectors with the number of days since 01/01/1970 (Unix time) and you want to get those time in the human readable format `formatOut`.

Please let me know.

```
%The date time form you provided
formatOut='mm/dd/yy HH:MM:SS:FFF';

%Get the data out of the struct
time = {s(:).device_date}';

%Sort the unix times
reordertime = cellfun(@sort, time(:), 'uni', 0);

%And convert to human readable format
renamedDates = cellfun(@(time) arrayfun(@(t) datestr(t + datenum(1970,1,1), formatOut), time, 'uni', 0), reordertime, 'uni', 0);
```